# How do I complete the torch puzzle in the secret chamber in Castle Dimitrescu?

Tags: resident-evil-village

In **Castle Dimitrescu** there's a room labelled  **Secret Chamber** on the map, that can be accessed after you find the **Iron Insignia Key**. There's a torch puzzle you can complete in this room to gain access to a coffin containing some treasure.

That's all fine and dandy, except completing this torch puzzle is really difficult. You don't have much control over the torches since you can't grab them (just push or shoot them around), and the torches are far enough away that they can't reach each other without some messing around. I managed to complete this on my first playthrough by just messing around with them... but it took a *very* long time, and it just felt like pure luck that I finally managed to accomplish this.

I'm on my second playthrough now, and I'm not looking forward to another round of random torch flinging, so I'm hoping there's a consistent solution  to solving this puzzle. I did some googling about this on my first attempt, and didn't have much success finding a nice solution to this. All I really find was people complaining about running into the same issues. There were a few videos, but again, they mostly just showed people randomly tossing the torches around. Shooting them does seem to be a bit more consistent (which you can see in videos like [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ClQDze9FjJg), but I didn't have much luck with that on my first playthrough, plus I don't fee like burning through a bunch of bullets.

Is there a a reliable way of completing the secret chamber torch puzzle in  Castle Dimitrescu?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I managed to stumble across a reliable solution to this by accident. **You can light enemies on fire with one torch, and then use those burning enemies to light the second torch.** You're actually required to do this for another optional puzzle much later on in the game, so I wish I could say I had the brilliant idea to apply the same solution to the castle puzzle, but in reality I just stumbled into it purely by accident.

What you'll need to do is to lure at least one enemy into the secret chamber with you. This shouldn't be hard to do, as there will be about 3 or 4 enemies on the path from the kitchen to the chamber, so just make sure you leave one of them alive. Then you just need to blow up the broken wall with a pipe bomb as normal, and fling the  leftmost torch into it (you can easily just push it in). Once that's done, just whack the enemy with the lit torch (or let them wander into it), and then just whack them with the unlit torch to solve the puzzle.

I wasn't able to record video of this, since I didn't think to record until much later on, but I do have the automatically recorded video of me lighting an enemy on fire for the Medium Rare Achievement for  a puzzle later on in the game:

Comment: I'll likely be doing a third playthrough of RE8 once I'm finished my Hardcore run, so I'll make a point to record and upload me completing this puzzle in full when I complete it on that run. For now, hopefully my description and this video of my getting my face ripped off is enough to get the idea across.

Comment: I was so proud of myself for figuring this out. I’m glad that it wasn’t too tough for you too. By the way, shooting at the sconces in the first room moves them much further than pushing them would

Comment: I never even considered this I actually didn't have much difficulty just pushing the torches. It's pretty forgiving. I assume pushing / shooting is the intended solution since unlike in the other room where there's an infinite spawning enemy to assist.